# ArgumentError (Invalid argument(s) (onError): The error handler of Future.catchError must return a value of the future's type)

Tags: flutter

ArgumentError (Invalid argument(s) (onError): The error handler of Future.catchError must return a value of the future's type)

```
final User? firebaseUser = (
        await fAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: emailTextEditingController.text.trim(),
            password: passwordTextEditingController.text.trim()
        ).catchError((msg) {
            Navigator.pop(context);
            Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Error" +msg.toString());
        })).user;
```

Comment: Can you re-formate your code

Answer (score 0):

Create async method to fetch user.

```dart
User? firebaseUser() async {
  return await fAuth
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: emailTextEditingController.text.trim(),
          password: passwordTextEditingController.text.trim())
      .user;
}
```

you can show toast based on null user.

```dart
checkError() async {
  final user = await firebaseUser();

  if(user==null){
    //show message
  }
}
```